# How to prevent changing certain widget's options after initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I'm currently working with jQuery UI Widget Factory, unfortunately it has [very poor documentations](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory).

Here's a basic widget (a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Etyee/) for testing)

```
(function($) {
    $.widget('ns.myWidget', {
        options: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        },
        _create: function() {
            console.log(this.options.min+', '+this.options.max);
        },
        _setOption: function(key, value) {
            switch(key) {
                case 'min':
                    console.log('min is now '+value);
                    break;
            }
            $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this,arguments)
        },
        destroy: function() {
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I understand that the Factory's private methods are pseudo-private and they can still be accessed directly with `.date()._privateMethod()`. As you can see I'm utilizing `_setOption()` to respond to option changes.

In my example I don't wish to expose `max` directly to the user (meaning I don't want the user to change it using `.myWidget('option', 'max', value)` or `.myWidget({max: value})` but at the same time I want to expose `min`.

So to summarize:

- I want to user to be able to initialize (instantiate) the widget with any option they want (it's already implemented and working).
- I do **not** want the user to be able to change `max` using the public API after initialization (meaning it's okay if the user changes `max` by accessing the instance directly with `.data` or with the widget's `.prototype`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of head scratching I found it! In my overriding `_setOption` I just had to ignore `max`.

```
_setOption: function (key, value) {
   switch (key) {
   case 'min':
      console.log('min is now ' + value);
      break;
   case 'max':
      return; //*
   }
   $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

* exiting here will prevent calling `$.Widget.prototype._setOption` thus the options will not be updated.